# Ruby on Rails Bundler issues LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I believe I am having some PATH issues for my gems.

I am using rvm (version 1.29.3) with ruby (version 2.4.1) and rails (version 5.1.4)

I tried to run `rails new myapp` to which I get the following LoadErrors:

```
remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb
run  bundle install
   /Users/fabienbessez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby: No such file or directory 
-- /Users/fabienbessez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
   2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle (LoadError)
run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
   /Users/fabienbessez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby: No such file or directory 
   -- /Users/fabienbessez/.rvm/rubies/ruby 
   2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle (LoadError)
```

I get the same error when I try to then run `bundle install`

I checked the contents of `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems` to which I found that `bundler-1.15.4` but not `bundler-1.16.0`. I assume that that is the issue. But I can't figure out how to update those gems. `gem install bundler` says it has installed bundler 1.16.0 but this is not being updated.

Any ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: type 'ruby -v' and 'which bundle' in console, what do they say?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to uninstall all old versions of bundler with `gem uninstall bundler`?